# MySQL filtering by timestamp by truncating hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've connected a datetimepicker client side to filter results based on a date range, but I can't get the  date picker date chosen to include the date on the server.  So for example if I chose dateTo to be Nov 6, 2014 the results won't include that record, but if I chose Nov 7, 2014 it will include Nov 6, 2014.  I'm sure this has to do with the unixtimestamp on the server including H:M:S, but I can't figure out how to truncate them.  I tried using DATE_FORMAT and even FROM_UNIXTIME using '%M %d, %Y', but the range returned isn't right from either, this seems the closest so far.

PHP converting Nov 6, 2014 (or equiv date) to timestamp and appending to SQL query:

```
if( !empty($query_filters['dateFrom']) && !empty($query_filters['dateTo']) ) 
{
    $sql .= " AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(packageinstance.created) 
              BETWEEN " . strtotime($query_filters['dateFrom']) . " 
              AND " . strtotime($query_filters['dateTo']);
}
else if( !empty($query_filters['dateFrom']) && empty($query_filters['dateTo']) ) 
{
    $sql .= " AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(packageinstance.created) >= " . strtotime($query_filters['dateFrom']);
}
else if( !empty($query_filters['dateTo']) && empty($query_filters['dateFrom']) ) 
{
    $sql .= " AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(packageinstance.created) <= " . strtotime($query_filters['dateTo']);
}
```

Generated SQL

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
     packageinstance.id, 
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(packageinstance.created) as epoch_time, 
     user.username, 
     status.name as status, 
     package.type 
FROM packageinstance 
JOIN user    ON user.id    = packageinstance.creatorid  
JOIN status  ON status.id  = packageinstance.status 
JOIN package ON package.id = packageinstance.packageid 
WHERE packageinstance.locationid = 1 
AND status LIKE '%%' 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(packageinstance.created) < 1415228400 
ORDER BY epoch_time DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

What do I need to do to truncate the time in this SQL query from packageinstance.created?

**UPDATE**

Using @alu answer below for PHP date formatting, and then adding DATE_FORMAT this seems to be working, but quite verbose is this overkill?  Wasn't working with @alu answer alone, but it was instrumental.

```
if( !empty($query_filters['dateFrom']) && !empty($query_filters['dateTo']) ) 
{
    $sql .= " AND DATE_FORMAT(packageinstance.created, '%Y-%m-%d') 
              BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('" . date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($query_filters['dateFrom'])) . "', '%Y-%m-%d')  
              AND DATE_FORMAT('" . date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($query_filters['dateTo'])) . "', '%Y-%m-%d')";
}
else if( !empty($query_filters['dateFrom']) && empty($query_filters['dateTo']) ) 
{
    $sql .= " AND DATE_FORMAT(packageinstance.created, '%Y-%m-%d') >= 
              DATE_FORMAT('" . date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($query_filters['dateFrom'])) . "', '%Y-%m-%d')";
}
else if( !empty($query_filters['dateTo']) && empty($query_filters['dateFrom']) ) 
{
    $sql .= " AND DATE_FORMAT(packageinstance.created, '%Y-%m-%d') <= 
              DATE_FORMAT('" . date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($query_filters['dateTo'])) . "', '%Y-%m-%d')";
}
```

Generated SQL

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
     packageinstance.id, 
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(packageinstance.created) as epoch_time, 
     user.username, 
     status.name as status, 
     package.type 
FROM packageinstance 
JOIN user    ON user.id    = packageinstance.creatorid  
JOIN status  ON status.id  = packageinstance.status 
JOIN package ON package.id = packageinstance.packageid 
WHERE packageinstance.locationid = ? AND status LIKE '%%' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(packageinstance.created, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT('2014-11-06 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY epoch_time desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: A better approach would be to let the date picker pass a properly formatted date string itself. For example, [jQuery UI's datepicker has `altFormat` and `altField`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field) to pass something different than what the user sees.

Comment: I'm using a datepicker that has moment.js integrated into it, so I could use that, but it doesn't output a different date than it displays by default also using: moment('Nov 6, 2014', 'MM D, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'), produces 0014-06-20 12:00:00, which looks invalid. I also don't understand how converting it client-side, would differ from converting it server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 $sql .= " AND packageinstance.created >= '" . date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($query_filters['dateFrom'])) . "'";
```

Comment: Hi @alu that ends up returning no results, and when output to console using FirePHP it gives 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: what value in `$query_filters['dateFrom']` ?

Comment: It's unfortunately a string formatted for the user: 'Nov 6, 2014'

Comment: Sorry, it does work I had a bracket in the wrong spot, sorry it was a cut and paste err :(  I get 2014-11-05 00:00:00, but now I've got a SQL err

Comment: DB format is 2014-11-06 17:51:39 and with your solution I get 2014-11-05 00:00:00, but it throws a SQL error, even though they appear in the same format.  Updating my question above with current code.

Comment: Hi @alu, I've updated the question with what seems to be working now when I added DATE_FORMAT to your answer.  Is this overly verbose?

Comment: i think better then my answer.